# Printing linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

*I couldn't print the linked list it infinitely prints 4 as the value. What is wrong with this code ?* In the below code, I am trying to implement a singly linked list after adding every element while am trying to print it infinitely prints 4 as output any idea why?

```
  import java.util.*;
    class Linkedit{
        static class Node{
            static Node next;
            int data;
            Node(int t){
                data=t;
                next=null;
            }
        }
        Node head=null;
        public void insert(int data){
            Node k=new Node(data);
            k.next=head;
            head=k;
        }
        public void show(){
            Node a=head;
            while(a!=null){
                System.out.println(a.data);
                a=a.next;
            }
        }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Linkedit g=new Linkedit();
            g.insert(3);
            g.insert(4);
            g.insert(5);
            g.show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problem:

```
static Node next;
```

The `next` member should not be static, since each `Node` should have a different `next` value.

Changing

```
    static class Node {
        static Node next;
        int data;
        Node(int t){
            data=t;
            next=null;
        }
    }
```

to

```
    static class Node {
        Node next;
        int data;
        Node(int t){
            data=t;
            next=null;
        }
    }
```

Solves your problem.